# C program that tells the user which child process finished first

Tags: c, process, fork

I am working on an assignment that involves using `fork`. The program runs two separate programs simultaneously and tells the user which one finished first. If a child finishes, the other child still running should be killed immediately.
My code so far is this...

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  if (argc != 2) {
    perror("Invalid number of arguments!");
    exit(1);
  }
  pid_t pid;
  pid_t wpid;
  int status = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
      execv("/bin/sh", argv[i+1]);
    } 
  }
  while ((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0);
  printf("%s finished first!", <Insert winning program here>);
  return 0;
}
```

From my understanding, this runs the programs and will not let the parent process continue until the child processes have finished. Now I'm wondering how I can terminate another child and return the winning process.

Comment: Calling `perror` with an indeterminate value in `errno` is a mistake.  You're likely to get error message like `Invalid number of arguments!: Success`, or possibly `Invalid number of arguments: Not a type-writer`

Comment: Why are you looping on `wait`?  The first time `wait` returns, it tells you the pid of the child that just finished.  It is most sensible to say that child is the one that finished first.  Indeed, you could define "finishing" as having the parent reap the child's data from the process table, so by definition the pid first returned by `wait` is the pid of the child that finished first.

Comment: Your question was "How I can terminate another child, and return the winning process?".... 1) following the fork(), the "parent" saves the pid of the new child. 2) wait will tell you the pid of the winning process.  3) use "kill()" to terminate the 'losing' process.

Comment: But how can I immediately get the pid of the losing process so that I can kill it?

Answer (score 1):

> But how can I immediately get the pid of the losing process so that I can kill it?

Just as TonyB told: *the "parent" saves the pid of the new child. 2) wait will tell you the pid of the winning process.* More verbose: Save the PID of both children, wait for any one, compare the return value to (one of) the saved PIDs; the matching one is the winner, the non-matching one is the loser. E. g.:

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc != 3)    // with two program arguments, argc is 3
    fputs("Invalid number of arguments!\n", stderr), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  pid_t pid[2];     // to store both child pids
  pid_t wpid;
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    if ((pid[i] = fork()) == 0)
      execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", argv[i+1], NULL),
      perror(argv[i+1]), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  wpid = wait(NULL);                    // wait for first
  int wi = wpid==pid[0] ? 0 : 1;        // get index of winner
  kill(pid[!wi], SIGKILL), wait(NULL);  // kill and reap loser
  printf("%s finished first!\n", argv[wi+1]);
  return 0;
}
```